# How to check dependencies of libraries against classes in java

Tags: java

I have a java project which is previously developed by another developer, in this application there are a lot of unnecessary libraries. I was able to delete some of those libraries. But, as there are a lot of them I want to know whether there is a technique to scan the project and detect unrelated libraries to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [Tattletale](https://www.jboss.org/tattletale) from JBoss.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the build method, it should be easy to remove unnecessary libraries without deleting/adding them by simply recompiling the application modifying the classpath at compile time, or rather modifying the build files by one-by-one deletion of lib dependencies.  Either one of these methods will require no manual deletion of jars.

**1)** If you set the jars using the classpath manually, you can play with classpath wild cards to remove / add different jars when running : [Setting multiple jars in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath) classpaths .  This does not require manual deletion / adding of jars.

**2)** Find the dependencies definition (pom.xml in maven, ivy.xml for some ant projects).

and One by one delete the (maven)

```
<dependency>..</dependency>
```

or (ivy)

```
<dependency .... />
```

entries in your build file.

If you have the correct build plugins installed - then your IDE will immediately rebuild the project using your new definitions (no error prone removal/deletion of jars or classpath entries).

Comment: oh, sorry, I forgot to tell that this is a swing application which is developed using netbeans IDE.